# How extract regression results from lme, lmer, glmer to Latex?

Tags: r, latex

I'm fitting models with lme, lmer and glmer. I need to construct tables with the summary() objects and export to Latex showing my results. xtable, mtable, and apsrtable do not work. I saw a previous post (link below) with a solution for lme4 objects, but not for these ones.

http://leftcensored.skepsi.net/2011/03/13/code-latex-tables-for-lme4-models/

These are two examples of the models I'm fitting:

```
lme(y ~  time, data, na.action=na.omit, method="REML", random = ~ 1 | subject, control=lmeControl(msMaxIter = 200, msVerbose = TRUE))

glmer(y ~ time + (time | subject), data, family=binomial(link = "logit"), REML=T, control=list(maxIter = 800, maxFN=1000, msVerbose = TRUE))
```

Any help?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `lme`, my personal version is below; you can download it with other similar addons, e.g. to extract `\Sexpr{}` string for p-values of lme/lm/glm tables as Dmisc from

http://www.menne-biomed.de/download

This is very personalized, but if I like the rounding to really significant digits a lot. Sorry, package nlme does all I need (and more than lme/gaussian), so there is not lme4 version yet.

```
"latex.summary.lme" <-
function(object, title="",parameter=NULL, file="",
  shadep=0.05,caption=NULL,label=NULL,ctable=FALSE,form=NULL,
  interceptp = FALSE, moredec=0, where="!htbp", ...) {
  # This function can be mis-used for gls models when an explicit
  # form is given
  options(Hverbose=FALSE)
  require('Hmisc')
  require('nlme')
  dd <- object$dims
  method <- object$method
  fixF <- object$call$fixed
  xtTab <- as.data.frame(object$tTable)
  sigp <- xtTab[,"p-value"]< shadep # cells that will be shaded
  if (!interceptp){
    sigp[1] <- FALSE # intercept will never be shaded
    # Replace small significances, discarding p-value for (Intercept)
    xtTab[1,"p-value"] = 1 # we do not show it anyway, easier formatting
  }
  pval <- format(zapsmall(xtTab[, "p-value"],4))
  pval[as.double(pval) < 0.0001] <- "$< .0001$"
  xtTab[, "p-value"] <- pval
  xtTab[,"t-value"] <- round(xtTab[,"t-value"],1)
  if (ncol(xtTab) == 5) # not for gls
    xtTab[,"DF"] <- as.integer(xtTab[,"DF"])
  # extract formula
  if (is.null(form)) {
    if (!is.null(object$terms)) {
      form=object$terms
    } else {
      form = formula(object)
    }
  }
  if (is.null(parameter)) {
    parameter=as.character(form[[2]])
  }
  if (any(wchLv <- (as.double(levels(xtTab[, "p-value"])) == 0))) {
      levels(xtTab[, "p-value"])[wchLv] <- "<.0001"
  }
  if (is.null(label))
    label <- lmeLabel("contr",form)
  form <- deparse(removeFormFunc(as.formula(form)),width.cutoff=500)

  form <- paste(sub('~','$\\\\sim$ ',form),sep="")
  # All I( in factors are replaced with (This could be improved)
  row.names(xtTab) <- 
    gsub("I\\(","(",dimnames(object$tTable)[[1]])
  row.names(xtTab) <-  gsub("\\^2","\\texttwosuperior",row.names(xtTab))

  # Determine base level  
  levs <- lapply(object$contrasts,function(object) {dimnames(object)[[1]][1]})
  levnames <- paste(names(levs),levs,sep=" = ",collapse=", ")
  # Try to locate numeric covariables
#  v1 <- all.vars(formula(object))[-1]
## Changed 8.10.2008, not regression-tested
  v1 <- all.vars(form)[-1]
  numnames <- v1[is.na(match(v1,names(levs)))]
  if (length(numnames > 0)) {
    numnames <- paste(numnames," = 0",collapse=", ")
    levnames <- paste(levnames,numnames,sep=", ")
  }
  if (is.null(caption)){ # TODO: Allow %s substitution
    if (inherits(object,"lme"))
      md = "Mixed model (lme)" else
    if (inherits(object,"gls"))
      md = "Extended linear model (gls)" else
      md = "Linear model"
    caption <- paste(md," contrast table for \\emph{",
       parameter, "} (model ",form,
    "). The value in row (Intercept) gives the reference value for ",
      levnames,".",sep='')
  }
  caption.lot <- paste("Contrast table for ",parameter, " by ",
      levnames)
  ndec <- pmax(round(1-log10(xtTab[,2]+0.000001)+moredec),0)
  xtTab[,1] <- formatC(round(xtTab[,1],ndec))
  xtTab[,2] <- formatC(round(xtTab[,2],ndec))
  if (ncol(xtTab) == 5) {
    names(xtTab) <- c("Value","StdErr","DF","t","p")
    pcol = 5
  } else {# gls misuse
    names(xtTab) <- c("Value","StdErr","t","p")
    pcol = 4
  }
  # Only show intercept p/t when explicitely required
  if (!interceptp){
    xtTab[1,pcol-1] <- NA
    xtTab[1,pcol] <- ''
  }
  cellTex <- matrix(rep("", NROW(xtTab) * NCOL(xtTab)), nrow=NROW(xtTab))
  cellTex[sigp,pcol] <- "cellcolor[gray]{0.9}"
  rowlabel <- ifelse(nchar(parameter) >9,"",parameter)
  latex(xtTab, title=title, file=file, caption=caption,caption.lot=caption.lot,
    caption.loc="bottom", label=label, cellTexCmds = cellTex,
    rowlabel=rowlabel, ctable=ctable, where=where,
    booktabs = !ctable, numeric.dollar=FALSE,col.just=rep("r",5),...)
}

"latex.lme" <-
function(object, title="",parameter=NULL,file="",shadep=0.05,
  caption=NULL,label=NULL,ctable=FALSE,form=NULL,
  interceptp=FALSE,  moredec= 0, where="!htbp",...) {
  options(Hverbose=FALSE)
  require('Hmisc')
  require('nlme')
  latex.summary.lme(summary(object),title=title,parameter=parameter, 
    file=file, shadep=shadep, caption=caption,
    label=label, ctable=ctable, form=form, moredec=moredec, where=where,...)
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when I use your function. Could you help me? The error is 'Error in `[.data.frame`(xtTab, , "p-value") : undefined columns selected'

Comment: Could it be a language problem? Check if in your locale there is a columen "p-value" when you so a summary(lme(....))

Answer (score 9):

I just found out that there exists a `coef` method for `summary.mer` objects which provides all the necessary data (for the fixed effects). The returned object (after coercion to `data.frame`) can than easily be handed over to the formatting package of choice (e.g., `xtable` or `ascii`).
See the following example (which only produces the usable `data.frame`):

```
require(lme4)

gm1 <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period + (1 | herd),
              family = binomial, data = cbpp)

(res.table <- as.data.frame(coef(summary(gm1))))
##             Estimate Std. Error z value        Pr(>|z|)
## (Intercept)  -1.3985     0.2279  -6.137 0.0000000008416
## period2      -0.9923     0.3054  -3.249 0.0011562741408
## period3      -1.1287     0.3260  -3.462 0.0005368285553
## period4      -1.5804     0.4288  -3.686 0.0002282168737
```

Answer (score 6):

Edit:

At the time of edit the lme4 package has updated and memisc no longer works with these objects. Package texreg is an alternative. I've left this answer up in case memisc gets updated and it starts working again.

The [memisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/memisc/memisc.pdf) package does lme4 tables:

Here's a snippet of some code I wrote:

```
GPusenonMH=lmer(GPEtc_c~Age.y+Measure+Gender+Marital2+Work2+(1|NHS), family="poisson", data=subset(lemurdata, Measure %in% c(1,3)))

model1=mtable(GPusetotal, GPuseMH, GPusenonMH, summary.stats=FALSE)

toLatex(model1)
```

Obviously you could turn summary.stats=TRUE if you wanted any of that stuff.

Note that the dcolumn and booktabs Latex packages are both used by default so either put them in your Latex preamble or turn them off using the commands in the helpfile (useBooktabs=FALSE, useDcolumn=FALSE).

Comment: Thanks for this!  `mtable` works beautifully with my GLMERs.  The help page (`?mtable`) is really useful, too, for showing how to relabel your variables and models in more formal terms than you might choose to use in R

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution: Suppose `fit` is the result of your lme model, e.g. `fit <- lme(...)`.  If you want to have all the variables displayed by `summary(fit)` you can simply type

```
> fit_text <- unclass(fit)
> attributes(fit_text)
```

and you will see the structure-like result.  Then you can save certain components of the summary report into a txt file or Rdata file.